# auto run a service function when a page is visited

Tags: angularjs

The routing.js code below injects a given page using $routeProvider. Each page has it's own controller which uses the service ToggleFactory.

Is there a way to automatically fire up the function "menuToggle" of the service "TogglerFactory" whenever the page is visited? Thanks

```js
//---routing.js----------------------------
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('appModule')
        .config(['$routeProvider', routing]);

    function routing ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/page1', {
            url: "/page1",
            templateUrl: 'views/page1.html',
            controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
        })
            .when('/page2', {
                url: "/page2",
                templateUrl: 'views/page2.html',
                controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
            })
    }
})();

//---page1Ctrl.js------------------------
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('appModule')
        .controller('Page1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'TogglerFactory', page1Ctrl]);

    function page1Ctrl($scope, Toggler) {
        $scope.menuToggle = Toggler.menuToggle;
    }
})();

//---menuToggle.js-----------------------
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('appModule')
        .factory('TogglerFactory', function($rootScope) {
            var TogglerFactory = {};

            TogglerFactory.menuToggle = function(){
                $rootScope.clicked = !$rootScope.clicked;
            }

            return TogglerFactory;
        });
}());
```

Comment: If you just call Toggler.menuToggle() method in your controller it will be executed everytime the route is hit (the page is loaded). Doesnt that work?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already injecting "TogglerFactory" into your controller, so just do

```
Toggler.menuToggle() inside your controller
```

**controller in general**

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);

appModule.service('TogglerFactory', function() {
    return {
        menuToggle : function() {
            alert("Inside ToggleFactory");
        }
    }
})

appModule.controller('Page1Ctrl', function($scope, $http, TogglerFactory) {
    TogglerFactory.menuToggle();
});
```

**for your controller**

```
   appModule.controller('Page1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'TogglerFactory', page1Ctrl]);

    function page1Ctrl($scope, Toggler) {
        Toggler.menuToggle();
    }
```

Comment: That did not work. Bas Slagter suggestion worked though :)

Comment: Indeed I said the same, but very generally. As per your page1Ctrl.js it is "Toggler.menuToggle() "